# Copy files from specific date in vba

Tags: vba, loops, date, format, copy-paste

I need to copy 10 files from a folder to another folder on a daily basis depending on a specific date.
The date is in this format: "05/04/2021". Script is taking the date from a cell, however the Date modified is in this format in my explorer: "05/04/20221 00:00:00"

I tried to loop through the files but I can´t seem to match the last modified date of the 10 files in the folder with the date from the cell. I assume it has to do something with the format, but I can´t figure out what exactly.

I tried several approaches of formatting the date. Below is my last try. Any suggestions how I can fix this?

```
Sub copy_files()
Dim curr_path As String
Dim new_path As String
Dim r_date As Date
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fname, fitem As String
Dim fdate As Date
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

curr_path = yourpath
new_path = yourpath


Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")
wb.Activate
r_date = Range("G2")


    SourceFolderName = curr_path

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

   
    i = 1
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        If FileItem.DateLastModified > r_date Then _
                FileSystemObject.CopyFile new_path
                i = i + 1
    Next FileItem

    Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at *FileItem.DateLastModified > r_date Then _* and examine the values of FileItem.DateLastModified  and r_date

Comment: They hold dates in the format I described: ````r_date = 05/04/2021"```` but it´s missing the time (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: `r_date = Range("G2") & " 00:00:00"` - why are you doing this? I think you're confusing the format of a date, and its actual value.

Comment: As described this was my last try ( more a desperate one) to match the format. Doesn´t work without it either

Comment: Again, a [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type) and its format are two separate things. One does not need to format the date to compare it to another date. Dates are numbers. Formatted dates are strings.

Comment: Okay, I see what you´re saying but then I think it should work if I declare ````r_date```` as Date and it doesn´t so what am I missing...?